# R - Impossible to install R in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates, r

I spent my whole day trying to install R and RStudio on Ubuntu 17.10. I tried every solution on this stackexchange but any of those worked. I tried to update the `source.list` from `apt-get`, create keys using `gpg`, but every time I try to run `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-core` the terminal says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.27) but 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
               Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, when I tried to use the gpg solution it always show the message:

```
gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

Comment: the version of libc6 mentioned is available for 18.04 LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6).  Given 17.10 is approaching EOL (2018-July), I'd consider upgrading to 18.04 LTS  (*I didn't explore further than first dep*)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 2):

I installed R and RStudio a couple of days ago on **Ubuntu 18.04**

The required steps for me with an otherwise fresh desktop install of Ubuntu 18.04 were:

`wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.1.453-amd64.deb
sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev libjpeg62
sudo dpkg -i rstudio-xenial-1.1.453-amd64.deb`

Comment: Since that package is named "rstudio-xenial" (indicating built for 16.04), I'm surprised it doesn't work on your 17.10 system, since that release is between 16.04 and 18.04. Could it be that you have other packages installed which depend on specific versions of some libraries and prevent the versions R requires being installed?